# onLocationChanged method doesn't call

Tags: android, location

I search a lot and also see a lot of post inside stackoverflow but no answered or it was not clear and complicated. it's simple i want to onLocationChanged() method called when i send Longitude and Latitude from emulator control so i wrote this code inside main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mrg.findlocation.Main$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And put this code inside Main.java file:

```
package com.mrg.findlocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

          final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

          // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
          LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

          // Define a listener that responds to location updates
          LocationListener locationListner = new LocationListener() {

           @Override
           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

           @Override
           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

           @Override
           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

           @Override
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();

            Log.d("MRG","It worked");
            text.setText("latti :"+latti+"\n"+"longi :"+longi);
           }
          };
          // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
    }

}
```

And inside manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mrg.findlocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mrg.findlocation.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then i send two value from emulator control nothing happened:
[image]

Are there anyone to solve this problem one time for ever? the code i pasted here it's very simple to reproduce and it doesn't contain google map or anotherthing

**Edit:**

This code is suitable for real device

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
```

This code works on emulator

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're requesting updates from the Network Provider and the emulator uses GPS provider.

Try changing:

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);`

with:

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);`

Answer (score -2):

Try to implements LocationListener on your activity class

```
public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener { 

@Override
public void onLocationChange(Location location){
// do something
  }
}
```